# Java two libraries depend on the same lib but different versions?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, dependencies

Currently I am using 2 packages in my project, let's name them `com.example.a` and `com.example.b`.

The problem is that these two packages depend on the same other lib, let's name it `com.example.c`, but not the same version. Unfortunately when I run my fat jar that includes those libs, I have exceptions indicating there is a conflict because `com.example.b` needs a different version of `com.example.c` that the one included into the jar.

To solve this I tried to relocate the `com.example.a` package using the `shadow` plugin in order to make each lib have its own version of `com.example.c`. Using gradle:

```
tasks.getByName<ShadowJar>("shadowJar") {
    relocate("com.example.a", "com.example.relocated.a")
}
```

But since the `relocate` method is not recursive, only the lib `com.example.a` itself has been relocated but not its dependencies so the problem was not solved.

Is there a way to recurcively relocate a package and all its dependencies in order to it to use its own version of `com.example.c`? Or at least is there a way to build a jar containing the two versions of the same dependency?

Comment: If you are using Gradle: Gradle does not load transitive dependencies by default, but it does, if you are using the dependency not with "implementation ABC" but with "api ABC". Maybe this will help you.

Comment: AFAIK, no native support exists for it...  But, several workarounds come to mind... you could wrap one of the versions (perhaps the older one), and take the time to fat jar all the deps into that, and then import the fat jar into your outer fat jar..  You could fork either of the versions and work out the differences in upgrading it (prob what I'd do).  You could open an issue w/ `a` or `b` (or both) and ask them to upgrade to latest....  That's just what comes to mind.

Comment: There is no easy solution. The most versatile one is probably the "module framework" approach that is used by frameworks like OSGi: Do *not* bundle your dependencies into the same jar as your main application. Do *not* specify those dependencies on the application classpath. Do load each dependency and its transitive dependencies explicitly through a new [URLClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) instance. (I.e. you need a separate class loader instance for each dependency.) Lots of work, tough to get right.

Comment: I think shadow relocate is indeed a way to go, but it seems to me you use it incorrectly. You should create lib A and lib B, each of them having a different dependency C and in both of them (or at least B) you should relocate C to another package. You should not relocate A or B as you do. Then in your final application you should use fat jars of A and B (not their regular jars) without any further relocations.